# [buildfarm] Missing package dependencies: %PKG_NAME%/package.xml

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pull request test on ROS buildfarm for [this](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/pull/37) and [this](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/pull/39) pull requests, both are in the same repo, errored with the following or similar:

http://build.ros.org/job/Lpr__ar_track_alvar__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/6/consoleFull

```
10:55:45 Scanning dependencies of target _run_tests_ar_track_alvar_roslaunch-check__tmp_catkin_workspace_src_ar_track_alvar_ar_track_alvar_test_marker_param_config-full.test
10:55:45 -- run_tests.py: execute commands
10:55:45   /usr/bin/cmake -E make_directory /tmp/catkin_workspace/test_results/ar_track_alvar
10:55:45   /opt/ros/lunar/share/roslaunch/cmake/../scripts/roslaunch-check -o /tmp/catkin_workspace/test_results/ar_track_alvar/roslaunch-check__tmp_catkin_workspace_src_ar_track_alvar_ar_track_alvar_test_marker_param_config-full.test.xml /tmp/catkin_workspace/src/ar_track_alvar/ar_track_alvar/test/marker_param_config-full.test 
10:55:45 checking /tmp/catkin_workspace/src/ar_track_alvar/ar_track_alvar/test/marker_param_config-full.test
10:55:45 the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'
10:55:45 Missing package dependencies: ar_track_alvar/package.xml: rostest, rosbag
10:55:45 ...writing test results to /tmp/catkin_workspace/test_results/ar_track_alvar/roslaunch-check__tmp_catkin_workspace_src_ar_track_alvar_ar_track_alvar_test_marker_param_config-full.test.xml
10:55:45 FAILURE:
```

Both `rostest, rosbag` are [defined as `test_depend` in package.xml](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/blob/dc584c9791a5d2c3bd4936609c0262343b352e1f/ar_track_alvar/package.xml).

FYI the same pull request [passes on Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/builds/236091719?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification).

---

UPDATE1: To the answer to Dirk,

> The error message indicates that it is failing because the rosdep database has not been fetched.

Where is `rosdep` called during `14.3. run tests` section?

And what would you suggest to let the tests pass? Since I only see an invocation of `catkin_make_isolated` before the error occurs, I can only suspect [`CMakeLists.txt` where rostest is `find_package`d](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/blob/b32295f552813203b9fb992e02c2b37fc30a646e/ar_track_alvar/CMakeLists.txt#L163), although this doesn't yet explain why `rosbag` is tried to be installed...so I am at a loss.

I even tried the following to run tests locally to mimic [14.3. run tests](http://build.ros.org/job/Lpr__ar_track_alvar__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/6/consoleFull#console-section-17) section, which passed without an issue.

```
rm -fr ~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/
catkin_make_isolated --pkg ar_track_alvar --force-cmake --cmake-args -DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=1 -DCATKIN_SKIP_TESTING=0 -DCATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR=/tmp/catkin_workspace/test_results --catkin-make-args -j1 run_tests
```

---

UPDATE2: I see, now I can replicate the error locally (I had to remove ALL `rosdep` dbs like below, not just one in my previous update):

```
rm -fr ~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/
sudo rm -fr /etc/ros/rosdep
```

> > I am not sure what you are using that for in your package though.

I need `rostest` for [`add_rostest` macro](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/blob/b32295f552813203b9fb992e02c2b37fc30a646e/ar_track_alvar/CMakeLists.txt#L179) I think, which is also [documented in Catkin's manual](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/rostest_configuration.html) so I think legitimate thing to do.
Also my test needs `rosbag` to [play a bag file](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/blob/b32295f552813203b9fb992e02c2b37fc30a646e/ar_track_alvar/test/test_markerdetect.launch.xml#L22), which I assumed legitimate as well since the Catkin's doc above shows a way to download a .bag file during test.

> The buildfarm does not setup the rosdep database for you since it doesn't need it. Therefore you can't rely on it being present.
> :
> `rosbag` is being installed since as you mentioned is listed as a test dependency in your referenced package.xml file.

Hmmm...sorry but I'm still confused. Now I understand that the buildfarm does not have `rosdep` db, but then I don't know how `rosbag` get installed.

Anyways, all I want is to run tests that require packages defined in `test_depend`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262558/%5Bbuildfarm%5D-missing-package-dependencies:-%pkg_name%/package.xml/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the section "13. Build Dockerfile - build and test" of the build output it shows the two test depenencies (`ros-lunar-rosbag` and `ros-lunar-rostest`) are being installed.

The error message indicates that it is failing because the rosdep database has not been fetched. Since the buildfarm doesn't need it within a job it doesn't call `rosdep update` within the context the package is being built. Therefore you can't rely on `rosdep` being able to query dependencies.

I am not sure what you are using that for in your package though.

**UPDATE 1:**

The buildfarm does not setup the rosdep database for you since it doesn't need it. Therefore you can't rely on it being present.

> And what would you suggest to let the tests pass?

Since I don't know what your tests are using the rosdep database for I can't give a recommendation.

> although this doesn't yet explain why rosbag is tried to be installed

`rosbag` is being installed since as you mentioned is listed as a test dependency in your referenced package.xml file.

> I even tried the following to run tests locally to mimic 14.3. run tests section, which passed without an issue.

Locally it likely works since you have a rosdep database - at some point you ran `sudo rosdep init` and `rosdep update`. You could delete the rosdep database and try it again and I would assume it fails the same way as on the buildfarm.

**UPDATE 2:**

> Hmmm...sorry but I'm still confused. Now I understand that the buildfarm does not have rosdep db, but then I don't know how rosbag get installed.

> Anyways, all I want is to run tests that require packages defined in test_depend.

The installation of test dependencies has nothing to do with the rosdep db being initialized / updated. Your job does have both test dependencies installed (`rosbag` as well as `rostest`). Both of them should be usable without requiring a rosdep database. So in order to find out why your package fails you will need to check what it needs the rosdep db for.

It looks like you are running `roslaunch-check` but without the necessary arguments. Please see https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/issues/341 with the same question. You will need to use the option described in https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/910 to make your test work without the rosdep db.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-05-30**:
Thank you for taking a deeper look. Passing `USE_TEST_DEPENDENCIES` arg seems to solve the particular issue. I also [added this info to roslaunch wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/roslaunch?action=diff&rev2=140&rev1=139) but not confident at all if the change I added is the best delineated.